# How to get value by key from JObject?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JObject like this:

```
{
  "@STARTDATE": "'2016-02-17 00:00:00.000'",
  "@ENDDATE": "'2016-02-18 23:59:00.000'"
}
```

I want to get @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE value from JObject.

---

This is a sample code that I've tried to do the task:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse("{\"@STARTDATE\": \"'2016-02-17 00:00:00.000'\",\"@ENDDATE\": \"'2016-02-18 23:59:00.000'\"}");
var key = "@STARTDATE";

var value = GetJArrayValue(json, key);

private string GetJArrayValue(JObject yourJArray, JToken key)
{
    string value = "";
    foreach (JToken item in yourJArray.Children())
    {
        var itemProperties = item.Children<JProperty>();
        //If the property name is equal to key, we get the value
        var myElement = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == key.ToString());
        value = myElement.Value.ToString(); //It run into an exception here because myElement is null
        break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

*Note: The code above cannot get the value by key from JObject.*

---

**Could you help me to find a way to get the value by key from JObject?**

Comment: You may want to look at this docs page:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm

Comment: Thanks. I got to learn more about this.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This should help -

```
var json = "{'@STARTDATE': '2016-02-17 00:00:00.000',  '@ENDDATE': '2016-02-18 23:59:00.000' }";
var fdate = JObject.Parse(json)["@STARTDATE"];
```

Comment: The LHS is a JToken if you want a string you need to put .ToString() on the right hand side.

Answer (score 18):

You can also get the value of an item in the jObject like this:

```
JToken value;
if (json.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
   DoSomething(value);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
private string GetJArrayValue(JObject yourJArray, string key)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> keyValuePair in yourJArray)
    {
        if (key == keyValuePair.Key)
        {
            return keyValuePair.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will not work if there is any sub category.